# Chage LinkButton background color in GridView using Javascript onfocus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, focus, highlight

I am trying to change the background color of a row in gridview when the user tabs through the rows and gets focus and loses focus.

I am able to change the foreground color of a label, (just was testing this) so I believe it can be done.

I need help writing the javascript that will capture the ClientID for both the Header of the table rows.

It probably looks something like:   document.getElementById("<%= ....

But I believe you have to define the grid first followed by LinkButton. Not sure how to do this part.

My code below will change a label foreground color, keep in mind I want to change the background color of the Header and Item Template.

All help is appreciated Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setheaderfocus() {
        document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID %>").style.color = "Red";  //works
    }
    function setheaderblur() {
        document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID %>").style.color = "Blue"; //works
    }
</script> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>GridView Select Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Test" ></asp:Label>

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="Button2" runat="server" 
                     onfocus="setheaderfocus()" 
                     onblur="setheaderblur()"                       
                     Text="New" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" 
                     onfocus="setrowfocus()" 
                     onblur="setrowblur()" 
                     Text="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>

    <asp:sqldatasource id="YourSource"
    selectcommand="SELECT * FROM &quot;TBL_YOUR_DATA&quot;"
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    runat="server" ProviderName="<%$ YOUR_PROVIDER %>"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a combination of `this` object in `JavaScript` and `RowDataBound` event of the `asp:GridView`. Pseudo code.

```
protected void ParticipantsGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "setfocus(this)");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "setblur(this)");
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "setfocus(this)");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "setblur(this)");
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
function setfocus(elm) {
    elm.style.color = "Red";
}
function setblur(elm) {
    elm.style.color = "Blue";
}
```

P.S: I am using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I am not sure how this would work???
When the user scrolls through the rows with the tab key (not using the mouse) the LinkButton "onfocus" calls the javascript function "setheaderfunction" which tells a rowdatabound event to occur. Not sure.

I was looking for a javascript which could pinpoint the gridview row attribute which has focus and change the color.